# Перегрузка свойств и методов в PHP

Tags: php

Смотрел статьи в интеренете, но ничего так и не понял, прошу помочь, спецы :)

P.S Не отправляйте читать php.net (я теперь только там и читаю)

P.S2 Если можно то пожалуйста подробно распишите, чтоб понятно было даже тем кто впервые читает

Comment: о какой перегрузке идет речь?

Comment: ну допустим когда есть два метода, но у них разный набор аргументов , а имя одно

Comment: @MaximPro такое разве в php есть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нет, такого нет в php, и под перегрузкой они понимают совсем другое

Comment: на php.net написано про магические методы, но как их использовать я так и не понял ибо отсутствует пример перегружаемого метода

Comment: @Grundy а что вы понимаете под труъ перегрузкой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так называемую, `тру` перегрузку вы сами описали - несколько методов с разным набором аргументов, но одним именем. В php такого нет. При попытке написать нечто типа

```
class cls {

    public function myFunc($arg1)
    {
        /* code */
    }

    public function myFunc($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        /* code */
    }

}
```

вы упретесь в

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare cls::myFunc() in .. on line ..

Под перегрузкой в php понимается, по простому говоря, использование необъявленных переменных и методов класса. Как раз с помощью магических методов `__%methodName%`

Например:

```
class cls {

    public function myFunc($arg1)
    {
        echo 'arg is : ' . $arg1;
    }

    public function __call($method_name, $args)
    {
        echo 'Trying to call ' . $method_name . ' with args: ' . print_r($args, 1);
    }

}

$o = new cls;
$o->myFunc(1);
$o->mySuperFunc(42);
$o->myUltraFunc(42,43,44);
```

Вывод:

```
arg is : 1
Trying to call mySuperFunc with args: Array
(
    [0] => 42
)
Trying to call myUltraFunc with args: Array
(
    [0] => 42
    [1] => 43
    [2] => 44
)
```

Таким образом, необъявленные в классе методы `myUltraFunc` и `mySuperFunc` прекрасно работают. Так как при нахождении необъявленного метода класса php обращается к методу `__call` и передает ему название неизвестного метода и его аргументы.
При удалении магического метода `__call` - встречайте

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method cls::mySuperFunc()